# Inicialização de matriz não funcionando a partir de determinada linha

Tags: c, matriz

Preciso inicializar uma matriz que contenha os valores em binario de 0 ao valor entrada, que neste caso é 15. A conversão de base e o armazentamento destes valores funciona bem até o numero 8. Porém, a partir da 9 linha, onde o ultimo digito deveria ser 1, apenas zero é impresso e isso se mantém até o final de execução. 
Aqui está o código que estou usando:

```
    int conversor(entrada)
{
    aux1=entrada;
    do
    {
        /*
        Na função usei o modelo da divisão continua para converter um número, que se dá da seguinte maneira:
        Usando um inteiro na base decimal, é divido constantemente até que o divisor de zero
        O resto de cada uma dessas divisões é apenas 0 ou 1, e ordendando da direita para a esquerda,
         o resultado é em binario
        */
        for (i=entrada; i>=0; i--)
        {
            do
            {
                if (aux==0)
                {
                    saida[i][aux]=entrada%2;
                    divisor=entrada/2; //Primeira iteração, usa o valor de entrada ainda
                }
                else
                {
                    saida[i][aux]=divisor%2;
                    divisor=divisor/2; //Termina de dividir o numero
                }
                aux++; //Proxima coluna
            }
            while (divisor>0); //Faz a conta enquanto o divisor for maior que zero
        }
        entrada--; //Passa para proxima linha
        aux=0; //Zera auxiliar
    }
    while (entrada>0);

    for (j=0; j<=aux1; j++)
    {
        for (i=3; i>=0; i--)
        {
            printf ("%d ",saida[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

E aqui está o resultado:

[image: Resultado do Código]

Já tentei testar apenas a inicialização de array para conter o valor binário de 9, 1001, separadamente mas quando executo nesta função este erro acontece.
O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: não coloque imagens na pergunta, coloque sempre só texto

Comment: Por favor, veja como melhorar a sua pergunta com o [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e veja esse [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como C é uma linguagem de nível relativamente baixo, a maneira mais simples de resolver este problema é através da manipulação de bits.
Este problema, apesar de fácil, não é trivial. Então, para criar uma solução é necessário seguir um raciocínio organizado. Isso é o que eu documentei no código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  // numero que vai ser analisado
  int n;

  // numero de bits em uma variavel int (normalmente 32)
  int n_max_bits = 8 * sizeof(int);

  // numero de bits em um valor, desconsiderando bits zero 'a esquerda
  int n_bits_in_number = n_max_bits;

  // exemplo:
  // 0  -->  n_bits_number=0  000..000000
  // 1  -->  n_bits_number=1  000..000001
  // 2  -->  n_bits_number=2  000..000010
  // 3  -->  n_bits_number=2  000..000011
  // 4  -->  n_bits_number=3  000..000100
  // 5  -->  n_bits_number=3  000..000101
  // 6  -->  n_bits_number=3  000..000110
  // 7  -->  n_bits_number=3  000..000111
  // 8  -->  n_bits_number=4  000..001000
  // etc

  // uso geral em loops, etc
  int i, j;

  // uso como mascara de bits
  unsigned int bitmask;

  printf("*\n");
  printf("* n_max_bits=%d\n", n_max_bits);
  printf("*\n");
  printf("* digite valor: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  // conta numero de bits a considerar no  valor
  // bitmask e' inicializado como 100000...000
  // a cada iteracao bitmask vai ser deslocado a direita
  // 100000...000 --> 010000...000 --> 001000...000 --> etc
  bitmask = 1 << (n_max_bits - 1);
  for (i = 0; i < n_max_bits; i++)
  {
    // printf("* bitmask=%08X\n", bitmask);
    if (n & bitmask)
      break;
    n_bits_in_number--;
    bitmask >>= 1;
  }

  printf("* numero de bits a considerar no valor: %d\n", n_bits_in_number);

  // ok, agora vamos mostrar a sequencia
  // 000...000
  // 000...001
  // 000...010
  // etc
  // ate' chegarmos no numero que foi digitado
  // (nao vou colocar em "matriz", raramente isso e' utilizado em C na vida real)
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
  {
    printf("* ");
    bitmask = 1 << (n_bits_in_number - 1);
    for (j = 0; j < n_bits_in_number; j++)
    {
      // printf("(bitmask=%08X)", bitmask);
      printf("%c", (i & bitmask) ? '1' : '0');
      bitmask >>= 1;
    } // for j
    printf("\n");
  } // for i

}
```

Agora, alguns exemplos de uso. Notar que o valor 0 não mostra nada porque não tem nenhum bit em 1.

```
[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./376830
*
* n_max_bits=32
*
* digite valor: 0
* numero de bits a considerar no valor: 0
* 

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./376830
*
* n_max_bits=32
*
* digite valor: 1
* numero de bits a considerar no valor: 1
* 0
* 1

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./376830
*
* n_max_bits=32
*
* digite valor: 2
* numero de bits a considerar no valor: 2
* 00
* 01
* 10

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./376830
*
* n_max_bits=32
*
* digite valor: 3
* numero de bits a considerar no valor: 2
* 00
* 01
* 10
* 11

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./376830
*
* n_max_bits=32
*
* digite valor: 4
* numero de bits a considerar no valor: 3
* 000
* 001
* 010
* 011
* 100

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./376830
*
* n_max_bits=32
*
* digite valor: 5
* numero de bits a considerar no valor: 3
* 000
* 001
* 010
* 011
* 100
* 101

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```

Comment: gostei da maneira que você pra mostrar apenas os bits necessários, e ainda sem usar `-lm`

Comment: no Linux, -lm é só quando se usa certas funções matemáticas, o código que você mostrou não precisa de -lm

Answer (score 0):

Cara, o seu código está muito difícil de ler e analisar, pois na amostra não se inicializa nenhuma variável exceto pela `entrada` e `aux1` então eu tive que supor o comportamento do código.Dito isso, eu fiz uma função usando a mesma estratégia e comparei com o seu código:

```
void conversor(int entrada) {

   int m,n;// número de linhas e colunas repectivamente
   m = entrada + 1;
   /*
   *   essa fórmula encontra a quatidade de bits necessarias para
   *   armazenar a entrada, que nesse caso é sempre maior número,
   *   que será o número máximo de colunas que precisaremos
   */
   n = (int)floor(log(entrada)/log(2)) + 1;
   int M[m][n], i, j, atual;
   for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      atual = i;// atual será o número que estaremos convertendo
      for(j = n-1; j >= 0; j--) {
         /*
         *   está percorrendo a linha da direita para a esquerda
         *   por que após a divisão continua devemos usar essa ordem
         */
         M[i][j] = atual%2;
         atual /= 2;
      }
   }
   for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
         printf("%d ", M[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

e cheguei na conclusão que o erro está no `do while` mais externo e na utilização 
das variáveis `aux` e `entrada` nesse loop. Não conseguir chegar na conclusão exata, pois como disse tive que supor o comportamento do código sem saber o valor de algumas das variáveis.

Comment: gostei da fórmula, voce poderia usar também `n = (int)floor( log2( entrada ) ) + 1;`